# Fibers and total spaces of vector bundles from sheaf theoretic approach.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

I am interested in sheaf theory and am slowly working towards familiarizing myself with it. This question is to further this understanding.

Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a finite-rank real vector bundle over the smooth real manifold $M$. Let $$ \Gamma_E:U\in\tau_M\mapsto\Gamma(E|_U) $$denote the sheaf of smooth sections of $E$, and $\mathcal F_M:U\mapsto C^\infty(U)$ the sheaf of smooth functions.

As far as I am aware most (or is it all?) information about the vector bundle is contained within $\Gamma_E$. Moreover, reading the wikipedia section about [Étalé spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_(mathematics)#The_%C3%A9tal%C3%A9_space_of_a_sheaf) and [stalks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalk_(sheaf)), I get the impression that constructing the Étalé space from the stalks is very similar to constructing the total space of a fiber bundle from its fibers.

However, the stalk of the sheaf $\Gamma_E$ at $p\in M$ is not $E_p$ but instead the germ of smooth sections of $E$ at $p$. The germs clearly contain more information, as they also contain information about the bundle on all infinitesimal neighborhoods of $p$, while the fibers only contain information about the bundle at $p$.

So the questions are:

- Is there any sheaf-theoretic way to construct the fiber spaces $E_p$ from the sheaf $\Gamma_E$?
- How is the étalé space of $\Gamma_E$ related to the total space $E$ of the vector bundle?

Comment: For the first question : the sheaf of rings $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ is a sheaf of *local* rings meaning that each stalk $\mathcal{C}^\infty_x$ is a local ring, with a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_x$ where $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the ideal of smooth germs of functions vanishing at $x$. Then $\Gamma_E$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-modules, in particular $(\Gamma_E)_x$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty_x$ modules. We then have a canonical identification $E_x=(\Gamma_E)_x/\mathfrak{m}_x(\Gamma_E)_x$.